# A design pattern to classify things

Tags: ruby, design-patterns

I have a list of web pages, each about a product. In the previous system we used a if/else statement to classify each page, like the following:

```
if title =~ /pet/
  13
elsif title =~ /therapy|SPA|massaging|salon|hotspring/
  5
elsif title =~ /present|gift/
  4
# and so on...
end
```

So classification is done by string keyword matching. Since now we are making a new system, I want to make sure there are rooms for extensibility. I was thinking that having a separate class for each classfication is too heavy.

And I think maybe have a method for each would be better, like have a `gift?()` and `pet?()`. However I think doing this also means hardcoding something in the logic. Is there a design pattern for doing this kind of classification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are all sorts of ways to do that sort of thing. Here's a couple ideas.

You could use a `case`:

```
case title
when /pet/
    13
when /therapy|SPA|massaging|salon|hotspring/
    5
when /present|gift/
    4
#...
```

That's not that different than your pile of `if`s though.

You could put your rules into a Hash:

```
patterns = {
    /pet/ => 13,
    /therapy|SPA|massaging|salon|hotspring/ => 5,
    /present|gift/ => 4,
    # ...
}
match = patterns.find { |re, v| title.match(re) }
match = match.last if(match)
```

or an Array:

```
patterns = [
    [ /pet/, 13 ],
    [ /therapy|SPA|massaging|salon|hotspring/, 5 ],
    [ /present|gift/, 4 ],
    # ...
}
match = patterns.find { |p| title.match(p.first) }
match = match.last if(match)
```

The values in `patterns` could be anything: numbers, strings, instances of some other class, or even Procs; I use this pattern with lambdas as values quite often, it offers quite a bit of flexibility. Using a lookup table like `patterns` also has the advantage of being easy to edit at run time; you could even load the lookup table from a database or configuration file. The Array form is pretty much how Rails handles its routing tables.

Comment: Thanks. In terms of performance is there a major difference between array, hash and select-case? Also would I use lambdas into select-case/if statements?

Comment: @lulalala: Performance, as always, depends on the specifics of your real situation. I'd suspect that the `case` would be quickest and that the Array version would be slightly faster than the Hash (but benchmarking is the only way to know). You could use lambdas with the `case` but there wouldn't be much point as it is all static code anyway; using lambdas in the Array/Hash cases makes sense because you're replacing static logic with interpreted data and lambdas are the standard way of turning small chunks of code into data.